# How to run aws bash commands consecutively?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

How can I execute the following bash commands consecutively?

```
aws logs create-export-task --task-name "cloudwatch-log-group-export1" \
  --log-group-name "/my/log/group1" \
  --from 1488708419000 --to 1614938819000 \
  --destination "my-s3-bucket" \
  --destination-prefix "my-log-group1"

aws logs create-export-task --task-name "cloudwatch-log-group-export" \
  --log-group-name "/my/log/group2" \
  --from 1488708419000 --to 1614938819000 \
  --destination "my-s3-bucket" \
  --destination-prefix "my-log-group2"
```

The problem I have with the above commands is that after the first command completes execution, the script will stuck at the following state, making the second command not reachable.

```
{
    "taskId": "0e3cdd4e-1e95-4b98-bd8b-3291ee69f9ae"
}
```

It seems that I should find a way to wait for `cloudwatch-log-group-export1` task to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have to crate a **waiter function** which uses [describe-export-tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/describe-export-tasks.html) to get current status of an export job.

Example of such function:

```
wait_for_export() {

  local sleep_time=${2:-10}    

  while true; do

    job_status=$(aws logs describe-export-tasks \
                    --task-id ${1} \
                    --query "exportTasks[0].status.code" \
                    --output text)

    echo ${job_status}

    [[ $job_status == "COMPLETED" ]] && break

    sleep ${sleep_time}

  done  
}
```

Then you use it:

```
task_id1=$(aws logs create-export-task \
  --task-name "cloudwatch-log-group-export1" \
  --log-group-name "/my/log/group1" \
  --from 1488708419000 --to 1614938819000 \
  --destination "my-s3-bucket" \
  --destination-prefix "my-log-group1" \
  --query 'taskId' --output text)


wait_for_export ${task_id1}

# second export
```

Answer (score 0):

`aws-cli` auto access to vim edit mode by default.

You can avoid it by setting `AWS_PAGER` environment variable is `""` before execute `aws` command.

```
export AWS_PAGER=""
aws logs create-export-task...
```

Or, you can fix it in to aws's config file (`~/.aws/config`):

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. But setting `AWS_PAGER` variable results in `An error occurred (LimitExceededException) when calling the CreateExportTask operation (reached max retries: 2): Resource limit exceeded.` error. This is because AWS can only export 1 cloudwatch log group at a time.